# Writing Formula on Calculated column in SharePoint 2010

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

In a SharePoint custom list , i am having a column named "Action" which is a yes/no button of values "Yes" and "No". Now when i add new item by opening the new form, By default i should be having "NO" selected and the message "Not approved" should be displayed next to it and if "YES" then "Approved".

I used the formula below but still not working.

=IF([Action]="YES","Approved",Not Approved")

Please let me know what is wrong in the formula

Comment: Is "Action" a choice field (drop down or radio button) or is it a yes/no field (checkbox)?

Comment: I don't see use of creating message calculated field here. You can write few lines of jQuery to show message. next to "Action" field.

Comment: Its an Yes/No field check box. I am not allowed to write the jquery.

Answer (score 0):

If Action is a boolean then do

```
=IF( [Action] , "Approved" , "Not Approved" )
```

*and your formula missed a "* (quote)